# Change the color of text in python shell?

Tags: python, shell, terminal

I'm aware that this is possible with the os module's os.system("color") function, but this changes the whole terminal what I'm looking for something localized to only a single string or variable output. Something in the standard library would be optimal as I want to use this on multiple computers without have to use py2exe or freeze.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please take a look at the answer for the question:

- [Print in terminal with colors using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)

If you can't install addtional modules, you can try to use
ANSI-sequences directly. Please note, that the method is not portable,
and it's better to use some special module.

```
print " "+ "\033[01;41m" + " " +"\033[01;46m" + " " + "\033[01;42m"
```

When you need somthing more powerful, I suggest you using `colorama` (pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama):

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

Another option, use `termcolor`:

```
from termcolor import colored
print colored('hello', 'red'), colored('world', 'green')
```

Comment: The above code prints ←[01;41m ←[01;46m ←[01;42m, I've heard ascii escapes aren't supported on all systems, but I've tried it on Windows 7 and XP and neither worked. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama

is probably the best thing